# BDD behave reports with jenkins - Change name of generated Test report

Tags: jenkins, bdd, python-behave

I run BDD behave features tests for multiple units under test .
so same feature runs multiple times , and I update the behave.ini to save the generated reports in different folders .
My problem is when displaying the reports in Jenkins they all have the same name ,TEST_,so it is hard to tell which report is for which unit .
Is there a way I can display the reports in jenkins under folder structure ?
or change the name of the reports to add the unit name running ?

This is my .ini file

```
[behave]
default_tags = -@xfail -@wip
default_format = pretty
show_skipped = false
show_timings = true
stdout_capture = no
logging_level = ERROR
format = rerun
    progress3
    pretty
outputs = rerun.txt
    test_reports/progress3_report.txt
junit = true
junit_directory = test_reports/
```

And this is how I display the reports in jenkinsfile

```
        stage('Run Tests')
        {
            steps {
                stash includes: "**/*", name: "workspace"
                node("rpi") {
                    script{
                    unstash "workspace"
                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh """
                        rm -rf test_reports
                        python -m venv venv && . venv/bin/activate
                        venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip wheel
                        venv/bin/pip install --upgrade -r BDD/requirements.txt
                        python runner.py $units  
                    """
                    }
                    }
                    junit 'test_reports/**/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
```

in runner.py I update the junit_directory to add the units folder

I am looking to display reports in this format

- TEST_F1_UNIT_1
- TEST_F1_UNIT_2
- TEST_F1_UNIT_3
- TEST_F2_UNIT_1
- TEST_F2_UNIT_2
- TEST_F2_UNIT_3

Instead I get

- TEST_F1
- TEST_F1
- TEST_F1
- TEST_F2
- TEST_F2
- TEST_F2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is having the same problem .
Turns out there is an easy way by just renaming the features and scenarios to include the unit name in the before hook functions .

In enviroment.py

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
feature.name = feature.name + '_' + context.unit.name

def before_scenario(context, feature):
feature.name = scenario.name + '_' + context.unit.name
```

This way the feature reports will include the unit names and be readable from jenkins